# Access database multiple users

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, networking

Hello i have a database created with only Microsoft access (meaning no sql have been used) is it possible to make multiple users use it from different computers and the datas they input gets updated in all the computers?
Can someone just briefly tell me how if the answer is yes,
Much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

I have on several occasions used the following technique with success:

(1) Split the Access Database in two:

- The Back End: This database should contain the shared tables.
- The Front End: A database for forms, queries and basically everything except tables.
  Instead of actual tables, this database should contain "linked" versions of those tables which are held in the "back end".

(2) There is a central copy of the front-end database, but no-one opens this directly. Instead, they run a batch file which creates a local copy of that central front-end, and then opens that.

This setup has the advantage that the central "front-end" remains unused, and therefore isn't locked, and so the developer can edit it. The users will get the updates whenever they next launch the database using the batch file.

A second advantage is that the "backend" can be upsized to a "proper" database, and the front-end could then remain largely unchanged, just that the linked tables would no longer be in another Access Database.